# Overlay div is not working when I click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem opening an overlay div when I click on the button. 
I'm using CSS to create the overlay and then jQuery to display the div. When I click on the button the overlay does not open.

What I'm doing wrong?

```js
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("overlay-search").style.display = "block";
}

function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("overlay-search").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.overlay-s-style {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay-search" class="overlay-s-style">
  <div class="search-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your post? (but that's a good thing)

Comment: How are you calling your functions? I pasted your code in a snippet but nothing happens, so you'll need to edit it to provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: You need to give your overlay a z-index greater than the content it should appear "over"

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to add the buttons to call the functions! It’a link with “onclick=“openSearch()” but still doesn’t work. I have other 2 functions before these, I don’t know if could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, as long as you are calling the functions.

I fiddled it together to make it clear. As already pointed out, there is no jQuery involved here, did you provide all your code?

```js
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("overlay-search").style.display = "block";
}

function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("overlay-search").style.display = "none";
}

var openBtn = document.getElementById('open');
openBtn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  openSearch();
});

var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  closeSearch();
});
```

```css
.overlay-s-style {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlay-search" class="overlay-s-style">
  <div class="search-block">
  </div>
  <button id="close">close</button>
</div>

<button id="open">open</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the functions but you aren't calling them anywhere. Add an event listener to the button so when it gets clicked, a function get called. Add in a case or an if statement to check if the overlay is displayed so that it knows which function to call.